# How to Load data to one table from Multiple excel files?

Tags: shell, text-processing, python, perl, php

I have to load data from multiple excel file into one table , Please help me to achieve the solution.

We are getting excel file from different retail shop which contain multiple column , each file is of different number of column and headers name.

So based on the excel file i have to create / alter the table dynamically to load the data which i am looking for a help to get any solution / open source utility.

***Code:***

using csvsql to load the data from csv to table but which creates different table for each file.But i am looking for something like below,

```
File 1:

col1,col2,col3

File 2:

col4,col5

Output table:

col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

Based on the column the table have to grow dynamically , Please help me to get the solution irrespective of any technology,

Comment: Well, you tagged your question [tag:perl], so what's wrong with [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://p3rl.org/Excel::Writer::XLSX)?

Answer (score 0):

`xsl` file is not that easy to handle directly, but I think you can convert it to csv file first, and then:

```
paste -d ',' File1.csv  File2.csv > onefile.csv
```

The `onefile.csv` will be in the form you want.